# Recycling census plastic bags

Tags: plastic

Yesterday, I received my census questionnaire. So have many millions of other Americans, recently.

These bags are not labeled for recycling, but are they recyclable? Can I put them in the deposits at my local grocery store with other bags marked "4?"

(Allow me to officially protest manufacturers of plastic that don't label them for recycling)

Comment: Hi. This is not about Earth Science. However, someone at [Sustainable Living SE](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com) might be able to help you.

Comment: Thank you, @Spencer. I did not know about this SE place, though I looked for it.

Comment: @macetw [there are almost 200 SE sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites#newest) to choose from :-)